# Incrementing variables using pointers

Tags: c, pointers

I'm very new to dealing with pointers, and my C knowledge is fairly small. I'm trying to understand pointers. I wrote the following code to print a list of variables (a to f) like so:

```
0
1
2
3
4
5
```

I wrote the following code to do this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(){
  int a,b,c,d,e,f;
  int *p;
  int i;
  a = b = c = d = f = 0;
  p = &a;
  for (i = 0; i < 5; i++){
    *p += i;
    printf("%d\n", *p);
    p++;
  }
  return 0;
}
```

The idea was it works through the variables and increments each by an ever-increasing number (i). I am assuming that as you initialize the variables at the same time, they'd be placed next to each other in memory. However, I get the following output:

```
0
1
2
3
-1218283607
```

If I change the for loop to only go from 0 to 3 (i < 4), it works fine, printer 0 1 2 and 3. But when I wish to print the variable f as well, it doesn't seem to set it.

As I said, I'm very new to pointers so I've probably overlooked something silly, but I've been looking through my code over and over, trying to work it out.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Thank you all very much :) it was just my ignorance about variables in memory then. I'll read more into it, thank you all for the help.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is no guarantee that `a, b, c, d, e` and `f` will be adjacent in memory. If you want that sort of guarantee you need to use an array.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main() {
    int a[6];
    int *p;
    int i;
    a[0] = a[1] = a[2] = a[3] = a[4] = a[5] = 0;
    p = &a[0];
    for (i = 0; i < 6; i++){
        *p += i;
        p++;
    }
    for(i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
        printf("%d\n", a[i]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Here `int a[6]` is declaring an array named `a` that can hold six integers. These six integers can obtained via `a[0]`, `a[1]`, `a[2]`, `a[3]`, `a[4]` and `a[5]`. You are guaranteed that `a[0]`, `a[1]`, `a[2]`, `a[3]`, `a[4]` and `a[5]` are layed out contiguously in memory. Thus the line

```
p = &a[0];
```

sets `p` to the address of the first element. Each increment of this pointer moves us forward one position in the array.

The second `for` loop shows that first for loops correctly sets `a[i]` to `i` for `i` in `{0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5}`. If you run this program you will see

```
0
1
2
3 
4
5
```

on the console.

Answer (score 3):

You forgot to initialize `e`. But yes, use a packed array.

Answer (score 1):

It isn't safe to assume that stack variables are arranged in memory in any particular order.

You need to use an array, a struct or possibly a union to gurantee the ordering of your ints.

```
union {
   int ary[6];
   struct {
      int a;
      int b;
      int c;
      int d;
      int e;
      int f;
      } s;
   } u = {0};

  p = &u.s.a;
  for (i = 0; i < 5; i++){
    *p += i;
    printf("%d\n", *p);
    p++;
  }
```

Comment: Even in the code above, there is nothing stopping a compiler from inserting padding between `a` and `b`, and `b` and `c`, and, ....

Comment: Compilers don't insert padding arbitrarily.

Comment: it's about what's allowed by the standard.  One could argue that the most logical thing for a compiler to do is to allocate storage for OP's `a`, `b`, ..., `f` sequentially, but of course, that's not required either.

Comment: I don't buy that.  Compilers may be _allowed_ to put spaces in there, but in practice, they can only do that if they are willing to break a lot of existing code for no good reason.  In fact, what actual compilers do is go beyond the spec in providing syntax for programmers to be _explicit_ in how they want structures to be packed - and choosing backward compatible defaults otherwise.